# Express as a trigonometric function of theta

Tags: trigonometry

Express $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ as a trigonometric function of $\theta$ without using radicals by letting $x=3tan\theta$ Assume that $\theta$ is in the first quadrant.  I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: are you sure that you want to use $x = 3 \tan \theta?$ not $x = 3\sin \theta$  or $3 \cos \theta?$

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: if $x = 3 \tan \theta$ is intended, then you will have to restrict $\theta$ not just to the first quadrant, you will need $0 \le \theta \le \pi/4.$

Comment: Or $x=3\tanh \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use trigonometric identities. Let $x=3tan\theta$ then we have $x^2=9tan^2\theta$

so plugging in to what you gave  gives, $\sqrt{9-9tan^2\theta}$ which is equivalent to $3\sqrt{1-tan^2\theta}$

Do you know any identities you could use next?

Comment: no I don't really follow you, sorry!  Identities are a little beyond me at this point.

Comment: Hm, interesting. do you have any ideas/ examples of what you did cover? or what you are allowed to know/use?

Comment: what is next? what identity are you planning to use? i don't see any way to get rid of the radical.

Comment: We briefly touched on identities, but, they are supposed to be covered in depth next chapter.  I have a cheat sheet and I could follow along if it's spelled out.  I've spent about 3 weeks with trig.

Comment: Michael, are you sure it is a negative sign and not an addition?

Comment: yes it is correct. also yes to tan.

Comment: and as abel mentioned, are you sure you must use tan?

Comment: Okay and yes as the other fellows have mentioned this will be quite difficult than. Please make sure this is indeed the right question and details. And if you could let me know the context as well. Is this just a topic on its own , or part of trig sub integrals?

Answer (score 1):

$x = 3tan(\theta) \implies tan(\theta)= \frac{x}{3}$.

Draw a triangle in the first quadrant of a circle. The opposite side of your angle $\theta$ should b $x$ and your adjacent side $3$, by definition ( that is, $tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{3} = \frac{O}{A}$).

Now solve for the hypotenuse using the Pythagorean Theorem, giving $\sqrt{{x^2} + 9}$.

Thus, to express this as a function of $\theta$, we may do this:

$sin(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{{x^2} + 9}} \implies xcsc(\theta) = {\sqrt{{x^2} + 9}}$.

Similarly,

$cos(\theta) = \frac{3}{\sqrt{{x^2} + 9}} \implies 3sec(\theta) = \sqrt{{x^2} + 9}$.